# How to change the value of a line in a cmd script?

Tags: powershell

I have this cmd script:

```
REM Environment-Variables which can be used for Programs
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------
set SDENVDataPool=13
set SDENVDataPoolPath=C:\ProgramData\
```

The value 13 must be changed. I have tried this solution:

```
$line = Get-Content .\script.cmd | Select-String -Pattern "set SDENVDataPool" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$content = Get-Content .\script.cmd
$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line, "set SDENVDataPool=14"} | Set-Content .\script.cmd
```

The problem is that the line isn't read correctly. I get the whole file.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Select-String -Pattern "set SDENVDataPool"` you are returning more than one line as both
`set SDENVDataPool=13 & set SDENVDataPoolPath=C:\ProgramData\` match that pattern.
If you change your Pattern to `Select-String -Pattern "set SDENVDataPool="` you should correctly return one match which you can then use in the rest of your script to set the content when you run this portion

`$content | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $line, "set SDENVDataPool=14"} | Set-Content .\script.cmd`